# Seaborn time series

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have a DF like that:

```py
   DAYS_UNTIL_DEPARTURE  DAY_TRIP    COST DESTINY              FLIGHT
0                   -31        13  324.69     REC  GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
1                   -30        13  324.69     REC  GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
2                   -30        13  324.69     REC  GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
3                   -30        13  324.69     REC  GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
4                   -30        13  324.69     REC  GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
```

I'm using this code to get my plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
sns.lineplot(x="DAYS_UNTIL_DEPARTURE",
        y="COST",
       data=stack,
       ci=None, palette="muted")
```

As result, I got that:
[image: Plot]

When I use the Power BI (line chart), in the values filter, I select the columns COST, and apply the MINIMUM and MAXIMUM of cost. Then I got that:

[image]

My questions are:

1 - How do I plot the graph using only the minimus values with Seaborn? I wish the plot like in the image above, blue line of the graph in Power BI.

2 - How can I plot the graph using two lines, one for minimus values and another for maximum values, as in the first image of this question (Power BI)?

### Data

```py
DAYS_UNTIL_DEPARTURE,DAY_TRIP,COST,DESTINY,FLIGHT
-31,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-30,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-30,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-30,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-30,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-30,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-30,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-30,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-30,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-29,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-29,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-29,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-29,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-29,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-29,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-29,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-28,13,324.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-28,13,265.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-28,13,265.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-28,13,265.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-28,13,265.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-28,13,265.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-28,13,265.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-28,13,265.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-27,13,361.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-27,13,361.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-27,13,361.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-27,13,361.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-27,13,361.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-27,13,318.66,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-27,13,318.66,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-27,13,318.66,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-26,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-26,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-26,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-26,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-26,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-26,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-26,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-26,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-25,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-25,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-25,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-25,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-25,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-25,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-25,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-25,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-24,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-24,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-23,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-23,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-23,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-23,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-23,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-23,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-23,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-23,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-22,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-22,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-22,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-22,13,306.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-22,13,306.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-22,13,306.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-21,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-21,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-21,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-21,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-21,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,248.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,830.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,830.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,830.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,830.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-2,13,1081.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-2,13,1081.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-2,13,1081.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-2,13,1081.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-3,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-3,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-3,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-3,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-3,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-3,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-4,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-4,13,830.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-4,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-4,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-4,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-4,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-4,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-4,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,930.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,830.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,830.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,830.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,830.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-5,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-6,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-7,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-8,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,732.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-9,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-10,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-11,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,651.59,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-12,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-13,13,581.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,248.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-14,13,263.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-15,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-16,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-17,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-18,13,520.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-19,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-20,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-21,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-21,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-21,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-21,13,245.83,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
-21,13,380.69,REC,GOL  G3 2810 (GRU)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- That is not a built-in function
- Use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to create the necessary columns in the dataframe and then plot them

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlob.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# use groupby and transform
df['max'] = df.groupby('DAYS_UNTIL_DEPARTURE')['COST'].transform('max')
df['min'] = df.groupby('DAYS_UNTIL_DEPARTURE')['COST'].transform('min')

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
sns.lineplot(x="DAYS_UNTIL_DEPARTURE", y="min", data=df, ci=None, palette="muted", label='min')
sns.lineplot(x="DAYS_UNTIL_DEPARTURE", y="max", data=df, ci=None, palette="muted", label='max')
plt.ylabel('Cost')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and time spent on that.
In case of future questions, I will follow good practices that you mentioned about how to insert data in questions and so on.
Once again, many thanks.